# I dont know the answer to the question so it is obviously off topic!

Tags: discussion

I see this quite often.  Most recently with [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/78806/16):

> you think this question is clear cut? I'm not seeing it. Other than
>   "seek legal help" there's no clear cut answer. [original](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78806/can-an-employer-backdate-my-termination?noredirect=1#comment223056_78806)

This question is actually pretty clear cut compared to some but it certainly requires some expertise that much of our audience does not have unless they have worked in management or HR.

And while this is the most recent example the site is littered with questions that are pretty difficult, in scope, but closed off topic (often company specific or legal) because most of our users would not know how to answer it or even find the answer, and less because it is a problem that is specific or requiring a lawyer.

Is there a way that we can improve the focus of close voting to explain that just because the question is difficult that does not necessarily make it off topic?

Comment: well, there you have the fine line between "I don't know" and "unanswerable".  You're unlikely to get 5 people who simply don't know. The problem is that so many people close questions like lemmings. That remains the real problem: people not reading and actually considering before voting to close (in many cases).

Comment: usually, we are complaining about "duplicate of" being used too often.  And as @ChristopherEstep said, it's far too easy to close vote thanks to the review queue not requiring anything other than a click on the close button once a question has been nominated for closing.

Comment: FWIW, in this specific case, I'd close it for seeking legal advice.

Comment: "it certainly requires some expertise that much of our audience does not have unless they have worked in management or HR." - is that any different from saying "it certainly requires some expertise that much of our audience does not have unless they have worked as a corporate counsel."?

Comment: @WorkerDrone - Certianly but there is a large contingent of HR and management folks that contribute here.  The numbers of general figures of those roles is probably along the lines of 30 to one or better in favor of management/hr vs corporate legal counsel.    So yes it is quite different.